# Django behaves differently in PyCharm and terminal

Tags: django, bash, pycharm

I was getting an error in my Django program, but only when I ran it from PyCharm, and not from terminal. I verified that the following things were the same:

- Environment variables in the run configuration and in my virtualenv's activate script
- Python executable from virtualenv
- Django settings file

Skipping the debugging process, I discovered that when I'd copied my environment variable from my activate script to the Django run configuration in PyCharm, I'd left in single quotes that changed a password, i.e:

.virtualenvs/.../bin/activate:

`SOME_PASS='THE_PASSWORD'`

PyCharm's run configuration password:

`'THE_PASSWORD'`

The quotes were ignored by the shell, but taken as part of the password in PyCharm. (So the environment variables *were* different)

The easy fix is to change the password in PyCharm. Does anyone know how to have PyCharm read from the activate script, and not duplicate this information?

Comment: Your virtualenv activate script is not a great place for this setup.  I generally have a "local" settings file that is gitignored and that the main settings file tries to import.  This would make everything run the same in both systems.